# Can I delete one of these windows partitions?

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning, windows-10

I've been googling around trying to figure out if I can remove one or more of my partitions. But couldn't find a answer for my case. It's a pre-built laptop HP Probook 650, It came with Win 8, and now has win 10 after clean install where the whole drive was formatted.

[image]

I've numbered the partitions with red numbers on the left side.
**1.** This 25GB part. has linux installed on it.
**2.** This 450MB is listed as a Recovery Partition. Can I remove this?
**3.** This is the main C:\ part. which has windows 10 installed on it.
**4.** This 1GB part. is a SYSTEM drive, which I don't know what does, may I remove this?

I've already removed a part. called HP_TOOLS, and replaced it with the linux part. Before I removed it, I backed up the content which was only a few MB.

Comment: Are you trying to delete Windows completely?

Comment: No, I would like one more partition, without having to convert my drive to dynamic.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother removing the Recovery Partition for 450MB, it's not too much space and it can be helpful if your system crashes, as it can restore your system to the state where it was shipped when you bought it.

Comment: I already have a installation CD, and the drivers can be downloaded from hp's webpage. If I remove the 450MB partition, i get 450MB of free space, yes. But then I can resize it into a bigger partition for my needs :)

Comment: If that space is too much for you then you can go ahead, I mean it's not a critical system partition and is used for recovery purposes only. The system partition *shall not* be removed. Reasons here: http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/

Comment: @nKn Thanks for answer. I've already looked at that article, but it says not to remove the _System Reserverd_ partition. On my computer, i have SYSTEM (D:) and _Recovery Partition_ with no drive letter. Does that make any difference?

Comment: No, the letter is just the name within your system, it does not make any difference. Even if it's called SYSTEM it's still the *System partition* and should not be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. This 25GB part. has linux installed on it.

As per comments by Moab, this will be (or was) the actual recovery partition.

If you have already replaced it with something else - Linux - then you won't be able to recover using it anyway.

If it still contains the Factory Image then you can delete this partition if you have created separate Recovery Disk(s).

- Many manufacturers now provide a recovery partition, where a copy of the original system configuration is stored.
- This allows you to restore your PC to a "factory" state, ie how it was when you recieved it.
- Sometimes they also provide a program that will create Recovery Disk(s) on DVD.

---

#### 2. This 450MB is listed as a Recovery Partition. Can I remove this?

As per comment by Moab, this partition does **not** contain the Factroy Image, but just the HP recovery manager software.

Note that a Factory Image will not fit in 450 MB (As an example the one for my Windows 7 64 bit laptop is 16.21 GB)

---

#### 4. This 1GB part. is a SYSTEM drive, which I don't know what does, may I remove this?

**No**. If you do Windows will not be able to boot.

> The system partition contains the hardware-related files and the Boot
>   folder that tell a computer where to look to start Windows. By
>   default, Windows 7 creates a separate system partition when it's
>   installed from scratch (as opposed to upgraded from a previous version
>   of Windows) on an unpartitioned hard drive. This partition is 100 MB
>   in size.
>
> Windows 7 can help safeguard the system partition by preventing
>   reformatting or deletion of it, and if the system partition is kept
>   separate from a boot partition (as recommended), it will not
>   automatically be assigned a drive letter. This means that the system
>   partition won’t appear in Windows Explorer, which prevents the
>   unintentional use of the system partition.
>
> When you turn on your computer, it uses information stored on the
>   system partition to start up. There's only one system partition on a
>   computer running Windows, even if you have different versions of
>   Windows installed on the same computer. However, non-Windows operating
>   systems use different system files. In a multiboot computer using a
>   non-Windows operating system, its system files are located on its own
>   partition, separate from the Windows system partition.

Source [What are system partitions and boot partitions?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-boot-partitions#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. If I understand you correctly, I may safely remove the _Recovery Partition_ since I already have a windows DVD and the necessary drives backed up?

Comment: Yes, but a Recovery DVD will reset to the manufacturers defaults. The Windows DVD (unless it is an OEM DVD) will not contain any manufacturer supplied software or drivers. These can usually be downloaded of course.

Comment: Partition marked Recovery is not actually the recovery image, just the HP recovery manager software, the 24gb partition holds the factory Image.

Comment: @Moab The OP siad "This 25GB part. has linux installed on it."

Comment: Does not change the fact that it is/was the recovery image partition. No way you can store a factory recovery image on a 450mb partition.

Comment: @moab - Yes, I agree. I will modify the answer.

Comment: @theusual Answer has been updated following the comment by moab. Please read it again carefully.